# MongoDB remove all matching items from sub-sub-array

Tags: mongodb

Just wondering what the best way to accomplish this is. I can think of some janky ways, but they don't seem right.

What I'm trying to do is remove all sub-sub-array objects from a documents. Like follows:

SCHEMA

```
schema {
  person: Array<{
    id: string;
    posts: Array<{
      id: string,
      comments: Array<{
        id: string
        tagged_person_id: string;
      }>
    }>
  }>
}
```

What I am looking for some way to delete all comments in every post for each person where the comment has `tagged_person_id == some_id`. This isn't my actually use-case, but it represents the same concept.

I know how to use `$pull` to remove from a subarray for one subdocument, but just not sure how to accomplish all of this in one query, or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per JIRA ticket [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) and the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with), starting with MongoDB v3.5.12, given the following document:

```
{
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "x"
                }, 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "y"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "x"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "y"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can run this update:

```
db.collection.update({}, {
    $pull : {
        "posts.$[].comments" : {"tagged_person_id": "x"}
    }
})
```

in order to remove all comments where `tagged_person_id` is equal to `"x"`.

Result:

```
{
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "y"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "comments" : []
        }, 
        {
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "tagged_person_id" : "y"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```